# Simple hover effect not working on mobile safari

Tags: css, webview, safari, css-transitions

I m trying to make a simple hover effect with some images in an html website.
The plan is : When you hover over an image , the image shades and some details appear.
The css code is this.

```
   /* Hover overs */ 

.folio4:hover .face { 
    opacity:1;
   cursor: pointer; 
}                                                                           
.folio4:hover img {
   opacity: 1; 
}
.folio4:hover h2 {
    opacity: 1;

}

.folio4:hover a.icon {
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateY(75px); 
    -webkit-transform: translateY(75px);
    -o-transform: translateY(75px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(75px);
    transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    -ms-transition: 500ms;

}

.folio4:hover a.icon2 { 
    transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    -ms-transition: 500ms;
    transform: translateY(75px); 
    -webkit-transform: translateY(75px);
    -o-transform: translateY(75px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(75px);
    opacity: 1; 

}
```

**It works on all browsers** except mobile Safari. What can I do for this to work?
Thanks in advance for every answer.

Comment: Mobile tends not to use hover states. Have you tried `:focus`? also you should have the unprefixed version of transform/transition **last** in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it, the hover effect can not work with mobile devices, due to the fact that the system does not see the hover effect, as you know it from your computer.
The only thing you can do is, is to set that hover effect as a on click effect only for the responsive design of your page, so the user has to tap on a picture and gets the details then.
Sorry if this is not the solution

Comment: Thats a good idea. how can I replace the hover effect with an on click effect?

Comment: Write an extra class for mobile devices in your css by telling in the css that, if a screen is smaller than 500px e.g. than those rules are used on the html. I am sorry that I could not help you out with a ready code, but currently I dont have the time to write one down for you. 

Try to google for responsive design in HTML and look for some CSS examples for mobile-devices...

The codes are basically always the same, as I mentioned it above they first say how big the viewport is allowed to be maximally, and when the users interface suits the CSS than the rules will be active